# BindingFailure was detectedMessage with Mono.Addins

Tags: c#, mono.addins

I'm using Mono.Addins for my project. Here my code :

```
static void Main()
     {
         string modulepath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", Loader.GetCurrentDirectory(), "modules");
         AddinManager.Initialize(modulepath, modulepath);
         AddinManager.Registry.Update(null); //**Error in here**

    }
```

I'm get an error :

> The assembly with display name 'Mono.Addins.CecilReflector' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 2. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Addins.CecilReflector, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Mono.Addins.CecilReflector, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'

Any ideas to solve this problem. Thank in advance.

Comment: Is `Mono.Addins.CecilReflector.dll` in the application path?

Comment: Oh thank @leppie. This is my stupid. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah my problem is solved by copy file Mono.Addins.CecilReflector to application path. Thank Ieppie.